# How to allow python to trust my server's TLS self-signed certificate: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, network-programming

This is not a duplicate for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error). I tried the solutions there and nothing works in my case.

I am using Windows and Python 3.6.5. I have a python script for a TLS client. The server I need to connect to uses a self-signed certificate. When I try to connect to it using my script, I get this error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
```

I need to parse the certificate. I tried to add my server's certificate `.pem` content to file named: `cacert.pem` which is in: `C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\certifi` and run the program again. Nothing change. Here is my scripot. Please help me to make the client make exception for this server as I trust its certificate.

```
import socket, ssl
import itertools

context = ssl.SSLContext() 
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL 
context.check_hostname = False

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
domain="192.168.56.3" # my server
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=domain)
ssl_sock.connect((domain, 443))

print("====== peer's certificate ======")
try:
    cert = ssl_sock.getpeercert()
    print(cert)
except SSLError as e:
    print("Error: ",e)
ssl_sock.close()
```

Comment: Hard to tell what is going one since there is no way to reproduce it based on the information. But, assuming that the code is using the cacert.pem where you've added the certificate then my guess is that the certificate is not a CA certificate, but only a self-signed non-CA certificate - which is not sufficient,

Comment: I think that this question is a dup of your other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055935/cant-receive-peers-certificate-in-opoenssl-python-client-using-ssl-sslcontext.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been idle for a while, but in case somebody is still struggling with connecting to a server with a self-signed certificate via Python `ssl` library:

You can use the `load_verify_locations` method of `SSLContext` to specify custom self-signed root certs (see [Python Docs for load_verify_locations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations)).

The forementioned code could be extended as follows:

```
...

context = ssl.SSLContext() 
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL 
context.check_hostname = False

context.load_verify_locations(cafile='/path/to/your/cacert.pem')

...
```

Be aware that you also need to include public root certs in case you want to connect to other servers with public certificates with the same client/context. (you could for example append your `cacert.pem` content to the certifi root certificates and reference that folder / path instead).

See also this Python docs paragraph for more information: [client-side operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#client-side-operation).